# Binary literal to Binary string conversion in python

Tags: python, string, binary, literals

I want to convert binary literal like 0b01011 into the binary string like 0101101101 .
How i should go in here.

here suppose A=81 (hex)

```
>>> a = bin(int(str('A'),16))
>>> print a
```

returns 0b1010 and i want like 10000001 (binary string)

Comment: How are you intending to get `1010110` from the number ten (or the number one hundred twenty-nine)?  If you just don't want the `0b` at the front, you can chop it off with `a[2:]`.

Comment: Try `format(81, 'b')`.

Comment: i meant i want the conversion from any binary literal to its corresponding string. so dont consider what i wrote in literal and string

Comment: Or simply `a[2:]` (side note: how on earth did you get `0b0101`? I mean the leading zero?? the one after `0b`)

Comment: see, after putting A=81 (A in hex), i get the binary literal 0b1010 though its binary string representation is 10000001 which is what i want

Comment: How did you put "A in hex"?

Comment: @user3098378 You need to use `0x` in front of 81 to make it a hex:  `format(0x81, 'b')` --> `'10000001'`

Comment: So I guess you're looking for this: `bin(int(str(A),16))[2:]` (note the lack of `''`)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary the hardware i am using return the value in hex,  i didn't mention that how it returns. and next i wanted is to get its string representation

Comment: @BrenBarn the hardware i am using return the value in hex, i didn't mention that how it returns. and next i wanted is to get its string representation

Comment: @user3098378: I suggest you restructure your question.  If you are getting your data from an external source, then it is not a literal, and if it is in hex, then it is not in binary, so I don't see how your question is about "a binary literal" in any way.  Please ask the question you actually want answered.

Comment: @user3098378 Then [freakish's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872478/binary-literal-to-binary-string-conversion-in-python#comment31319474_20872478) should work for you. Though I would use `format`: `format(int(str(A), 16), 'b')`.
`

Comment: @BrenBarn i have already implemented other features in RaspberryPi. the hardware which i am using along with Rpi always returns in hex outputs. but to make them readable, i needed to convert them the hex returned to binary strings

Comment: @user3098378: Sure, fine, but edit your question so it says what data you have and what output you want.  The question as written does not make sense, and doesn't seem to bear any relation to what you're trying to do.

Comment: suppose my output is of 6bit (101001) or 7(1001110) bit and i want to add 0s at the starting to make it an 8 bit output, how to do it? also tell is it possible to do it automatically only after python sees the output is not of 8 bit?

Answer (score 5):

With python's newer string handling:

```
>>> print '{:08b}'.format(81)
01010001

>>> print '{:08b}'.format(ord('A'))
01000001
```

The '08' specifies an output size of 8, padded with zeros, so this this, by default, shows a whole byte.  Without the zero, it is padded with spaces:

```
>>>  print '{:8b}'.format(ord('A'))
 1000001
```

Without the '8', the output string is only as large as needed:

```
>>> print '{:b}'.format(ord('A'))
1000001
```

Comment: Or just with `'{:b}'.format(81)` if you don't want to specify a minimum number of characters to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you're asking, but you can just do what you're already doing and chop off the `0b`:

```
>>> bin(0b110110)[2:]
'110110'
```

When you enter a binary literal, it turns into a number.  The number doesn't depend on its representation in binary or any other base; it's just stored as an integer value.  So it doesn't matter whether you input it as a binary literal or not, you can still use `bin` to get its binary string representation.

Comment: see, after putting A=81 (A in hex), i get the binary literal 0b1010 though its binary string representation is 10000001 which is what i want

Comment: @user3098378: What do you mean "A in hex"?  How did you put "A in hex"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `ord` function to convert the string `'A'` into its corresponding ASCII character. (Applying `str` to `'A'` doesn't achieve anything.) Then you can convert that integer into a binary string, thus:

```
>>> print ord('A')
65
>>> a = bin(ord('A'))
>>> print a
0b1000001
```

If you don't want the `'0b'` prefix:

```
>>> print a[2:]
1000001
```

Comment: yeah. m not getting the required output, but same output for different inputs

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary How is it incorrect? This answer was written based on the code in original question, and before the comment discussion above. It is still quite unclear precisely what the poster is asking, but presumably if they accepted it, there was something useful in there.

Comment: @user3098378 Please clarify your question. There is too much confusion about what you're actually asking. What inputs do you have, and what output format are you after?

Comment: suppose my output is of 6bit (101001) or 7(1001110) bit and i want to add 0s at the starting to make it an 8 bit output, how to do it? also tell is it possible to do it automatically only after python sees the output is not of 8 bit?

Comment: @gavin i got my answer to the initial question, now its my another query i asked above

Comment: @user3098378 If you want to format your numeric value as a binary string with leading zeroes, then the answer by John1024 above shows you how.  The numeric values implicitly have leading zeroes. BUT - there's clearly some important info you're not including in the question. Where is this data coming from and going to?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand (based on comments) you get the number as an **integer**:

```
A = 81
```

and then you want to **interpret** it as hexadecimal. In order to do that cast it to a string (note that I'm casting a variable `A`, not a string `'A'`):

```
str(A)
```

then cast it to int base 16:

```
int(str(A), 16)
```

finally convert it to a binary representation:

```
bin(int(str(A), 16))
```

and take all characters from second position (ommit first two):

```
bin(int(str(A), 16))[2:]
```

Comment: suppose my output is of 6bit (101001) or 7(1001110) bit and i want to add 0s at the starting to make it an 8 bit output, how to do it? also tell is it possible to do it automatically only after python sees the output is not of 8 bit?

Comment: @user3098378 If you store the end result in variable `x` then (afterwards) simply do `x = "0"*max(SIZE-len(x), 0) + x` and define `SIZE=6` (or `7` or whatever you want) before that.

Comment: see it should be of 8 bit only.  if it return 8 then no padding of 0s, if less then that then accordingly left padding of 0s